# Deduct [Finance] from Tag Bank

Tags: discussion

The tag [Finance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/finance) has 36 questions and no description.

I thought maybe I'd add a description, but I can't find any discernible relationship among the questions where a [finance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag would be useful. The finance applications seem to have their own program tags and any financial functions or modeling within excel (or other spreadsheet applications) could use [worksheet-function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) or any of the other excel tags.

Comment: I would agree.  I didn't look every question.  Most seem like they are finance excel questions but not really anything to financial accounting.

Comment: Also worth noting that Super User is unlikely to have finance experts who would follow this tag. I really don't see the use for it.

Comment: Superusers have no interest in [tag:finance]. Only needs for [tag:finances]!

Comment: @Excellll You'd be surprised. SE has a site called [Personal Finance & Money](http://money.stackexchange.com/), and Money committers who came from SU might follow it. Case in point: how many SU users with 150+ rep also have a Money account with 150+ rep?